# Is it possible that Android App will not launch the MainActivity?

Tags: java, android

I am facing issue with my activity with main intent filter is not created. Also, it is not giving me any crash.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="tracker.com.tracker">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".Tracker"
    >

    <activity
        android:name=".TrackActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

And here is the code for my TrackActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class TrackActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_track);

       Log.d("Track","I am created");

       setHeaderTitle("Track");
       hideLeftMenuButton();
       setRightMenuButtonText("Show Stats");
    }

}
```

Here are the results:

1. No Crash
2. No Logs Printed in TrackActivity
3. Logs do print in Tracker Application class
4. No UI shown. It's just display an empty white screen.

What may be the possible reason for the same?

Comment: Use this instead `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Comment: "Logs do print in Tracker Application class": are you doing something special there?

Comment: Thanks Enzokie. It Worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
```

to

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```